# mongo group with match query does not work with java

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have below query working in robo 3T console.

```
db.metrics.aggregate([
{'$match':{'status':'SUCCESS'}}, 
{'$group':{ _id:'$bapiName',count:{$sum:1}}}
```

])

But when I execute it with java,

```
    MongoCollection collection =db.getCollection();
    List<Bson> pipeLine = new ArrayList<Bson>();
    pipeLine.add(Document.parse("{'$match':{'status':'SUCCESS'}}"));        
    pipeLine.add(Document.parse("{'$group' : {_id: {bapiName:'$bapiName',status:'$status'}, count:{$sum:1}}}"));
    Iterator iterator = collection.aggregate(query.getPipeline()).iterator();
        while( iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object object = iterator.next();
            resultList.add((Document)object);
            System.out.println(" class "+object.getClass()+" data "+object);

        }
```

I am not getting the results. Iterator is empty. Any changes need to be made in java to get it working?

Comment: `db.getCollection();` Which collection? Should have a name in it, and the same name as what you are doing in the shell. There's also a lot cleaner ways to return the cursor results as a list. Perhaps you should search some posts here.

Comment: Yes, i have a name. And thats a pseudo code to get MongoCollection. The issue is when I  use above code snippet, that is returning nothing. But when the same query is used in Robo3T, its working really well. I am just combining $match and $group. When I query with no $match, $group is returning results properly